# Add missing rows based on column

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I have given the following df

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'day': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 'pos': 2*[1, 14, 18], 'value': 2*[1, 2, 3]}    
df
```

```
    day pos value
0   1   1   1
1   1   14  2
2   1   18  3
3   2   1   1
4   2   14  2
5   3   18  3
```

and i want to fill in rows such that every day has every possible value of column 'pos'

desired result:

```
    day pos value
0   1   1   1.0
1   1   14  2.0
2   1   18  3.0
3   2   1   1.0
4   2   14  2.0
5   2   18  NaN
6   3   1   NaN
7   3   14  NaN
8   3   18  3.0
```

Proposition:

```py
df.set_index('pos').reindex(pd.Index(3*[1,14,18])).reset_index()
```

yields:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `pivot` then `stack`:

```
df.pivot('day','pos','value').stack(dropna=False).reset_index(name='value')
```

Output:

```
   day  pos  value
0    1    1    1.0
1    1   14    2.0
2    1   18    3.0
3    2    1    1.0
4    2   14    2.0
5    2   18    NaN
6    3    1    NaN
7    3   14    NaN
8    3   18    3.0
```

---

**Option 2**: merge with MultiIndex:

```
df.merge(pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['day'].unique(), df['pos'].unique()])),
         left_on=['day','pos'], right_index=True, how='outer')
```

Output:

```
   day  pos  value
0    1    1    1.0
1    1   14    2.0
2    1   18    3.0
3    2    1    1.0
4    2   14    2.0
5    3   18    3.0
5    2   18    NaN
5    3    1    NaN
5    3   14    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you. Works. I wanted to add that the first option seems limited to one column: E.g. if the columns are ['day', 'hour', 'pos', 'value'], and every day should have every possible 'hour' value, and every 'hour' should have every possible 'pos' value. Couldn't get option 1 to work, option 2 works fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can `reindex`:

```
s = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df["day"].unique(),df["pos"].unique()], names=["day","pos"])

print (df.set_index(["day","pos"]).reindex(s).reset_index())

   day  pos  value
0    1    1    1.0
1    1   14    2.0
2    1   18    3.0
3    2    1    1.0
4    2   14    2.0
5    2   18    NaN
6    3    1    NaN
7    3   14    NaN
8    3   18    3.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd avoid the manual `product` of all possible values.

Instead, one can get the unique values and just `reindex` per day:

```
u = df.pos.unique()

df.groupby('day').apply(lambda s: s.set_index('pos').reindex(u))['value']\
  .reset_index()
```

---

```
   day  pos  value
0    1    1    1.0
1    1   14    2.0
2    1   18    3.0
3    2    1    1.0
4    2   14    2.0
5    2   18    NaN
6    3    1    NaN
7    3   14    NaN
8    3   18    3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html) to expose the missing values :

```
#  pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor as jn

df.complete('day', 'pos')
   day  pos  value
0    1    1    1.0
1    1   14    2.0
2    1   18    3.0
3    2    1    1.0
4    2   14    2.0
5    2   18    NaN
6    3    1    NaN
7    3   14    NaN
8    3   18    3.0
```